# Is there a way to add python games to renpy?

Tags: python, tkinter, renpy

I'm coding a visual novel for a school project and I want to incorporate a mini-game made with python and tkinter. How can I do this?

I copied the code into renpy but renpy says "statement expected", and I don't think I'm doing it the right way. Thank you in advance!

```
label start:
"Welcome!"


from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title('Hello Python')
window.geometry("300x200+10+20")
window.mainloop()
return
```

What I get:
"from tkinter import-->* expected statement"...

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Also imo it kind of sounds like your tabbing might be off or something, you're getting a syntax error. But it would be much easier to figure out what's going on with some code.

Comment: Glancing at the [documentation](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/quickstart.html#supporting-flags-using-the-default-python-and-if-statements), lines of arbitrary Python code needs to be prefixed with a `$`.

Comment: I've added a $ before every line, and renpy tells me there's no module names tkinter. After looking into it, looks like it can't be added as it is not a pure module. Is there any other way? Maybe add a button that opens the file?

Comment: Your first line breaks the code so I do not think you are even getting to the from tkinter statement.

Comment: If renpy runs on a server, you almost certainly won’t be able to run tkinter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to launch other application (any application not only Python code) from RenPy code. Let's say this is your RenPy code:

```
$import os

label start:

    "Welcome!"
    $os.system(r"c:\renpy_test\game.py")
```

And here is your Tkinter game stored in `c:\renpy_test\game.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Hello Python')
window.geometry("300x200+10+20")
window.mainloop()
```

When you launch your RenPy game it then launches your Tkinter app:

[image]

Comment: my window opens in thonny instead of opening directly. Howcan I fix that?

Comment: Simplest way is to remove Thonny and install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [RenPy](https://www.renpy.org/latest.html)